# WCF - Calling the WCF service from the Presenter Layer

Tags: .net, wcf, mvp

I am new to WCF and I'm also learning the MVP design pattern.  I have a test project with a working WCF service.  I am able to test with the WCF test client and it works fine.

I need help with how to call the WCF service from my Presenter layer and then have the Presenter pass the data back to the View (winforms).    I have a Windows Form with two textboxes named txtProductID and txtDescription.  I also have a button named btnGetProductData.  I would like the following to happen:

1. I will put a product id in the txtProductID field.
2. I will click the btnGetProductData button and the presenter should call the GetProductData method from the WCF service and return the product description to the txtProductDescription field on my form.

Here is the pertinent code from the WCF service library:

```
IProductService.cs
------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace MyWCFServices.ProductService
{
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface IProductService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Product GetProductData(string ProductId);     
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    }
}

ProductService.cs
--------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using MyWCFServices.ProductEntities;
using MyWCFServices.ProductBusinessLogic;

namespace MyWCFServices.ProductService
{

    public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        ProductLogic productLogic = new ProductLogic();

        public Product GetProductData(string ProductId)
        {

            ProductEntity productEntity = productLogic.
                GetProductData(ProductId);
            Product product = new Product();

            TranslateProductEntityToProductContractData(productEntity, 
                product);
            return product;

        }

        private Product TranslateProductEntityToProductContractData(
            ProductEntity productEntity, Product product)
        {

            product.ProductID = productEntity.ProductID;
            product.ProductDescription = productEntity.ProductDescription;

            return product;                     
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your service looks fine, but what problem are you having on the client, specifically? EG: are you having problems creating the proxy, does it not return what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're having issues, so I'll start at the beginning.

1. You need to add a "Service Reference" to your Presentation Tier Project (this generates a proxy class you can use to call your service)
2. You need to create an instance of the generated proxy class
3. You need to call a method on the proxy class and store its value

From Visual Studio, right click your project and choose "Add Service Reference" and then navigate to the endpoint for your service.

Example Code:

```
// Presentation Tier (button event handler)
var proxy = new ServiceReference1.ProductServiceClient();
var prod = proxy.GetProductData("yourProductID");
txtDescription.Text = prod.Description;
txtProductID.Text = prod.ProductID; // same as passed parameter
```

Comment: You'd still add the service reference via Visual Studio, because it doesn't have anything to do with what programming model you're using.  One of the easiest ways for a beginner in WCF to use it in a WinForms client is to create and use the proxy instance in the code-behind for the form.

Comment: thank you for your reply and example. I have a question regarding your reply. Since I am using the Model View Presenter design pattern and my Prensenter class needs to call the WCF service, would I still add the service reference via Visual Studio? -OR- Should I be doing it as shown in the example code that I found below? Note: ProductService is the name of the WCF service class. ProductService productService; productService

Comment: Yes, you still need to add a service reference in order to use the proxy class I have defined above and that you are trying to use in the code you just posted.

Comment: The first two comments above are out of order due to my ham-fisted attempts at merging and editing.  There doesn't seem to be a way to get them to appear in the right order.